# Cite page only in biblatex

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

Given the MWE below, is there a way to use something like `\citepage[162]{9.47:4}` (or `\citepage{162}`) to only show the page number in parenthesis with the correct bibstring `p.` or `pp.` as defined in the `.lbx` file?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\begin{filecontents}{bibliography.bib}
@article{9.47:4,
  title = {General and Specific Measures in Organizational Behaviour Research},
  author = {T. A. Judge and Kammeyer-Mueller, J. D},
  volume = 33,
  number = 2,
  pages = {161--174},
  doi = {10.1002/job.764},
  subtitle = {Considerations, Examples, and Recommendations for Researchers},
  journaltitle = {Organizational Behaviour},
  date = 2012
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

According to \textcite{9.47:4}, lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit \citepage[162]{9.47:4}.

\end{document}
```

**Expected Output** [image: 1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\pnotecite[][]{}` is designed to do what you want, if I've understood correctly.

[image: post note in parentheses sans label]

```
\begin{filecontents}{bibliography.bib}
@article{9.47:4,
  title = {General and Specific Measures in Organizational Behaviour Research},
  author = {T. A. Judge and Kammeyer-Mueller, J. D},
  volume = 33,
  number = 2,
  pages = {161--174},
  doi = {10.1002/job.764},
  subtitle = {Considerations, Examples, and Recommendations for Researchers},
  journaltitle = {Organizational Behaviour},
  date = 2012
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}

According to \textcite{9.47:4}, lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit \pnotecite[162]{9.47:4}.

\end{document}
```

If you do not want parentheses, `\notecite[][]{}`; for a footnote `\fnotecite[][]{}`. Uppercase versions of all three commands are also available.